# Next.js Image component not shown in preview from browser

Tags: image, next.js

Why is the Next.js `Image` component not showing the image in the document preview of the Chrome network tab?

Why? I am concerned if that affects the SEO of the website.

I am using this code, but already tried other formats, everything server side rendered:

```
<Image
  src={dynamiImgSrc}
  alt={dynamicImgAlt}
  width={1}
  height={1}
  layout="responsive"
  objectFit="cover"
/>
```

Chrome preview tab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Qz3.jpg

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you mean by _preview of the chrome network tab?_

Comment: @Ramakay screenshot added to the post (https://imgur.com/a/yc3m3eo)

Comment: You may want to update the image with what you're currently seeing in your app, otherwise it may mislead people.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that you are passing 1x1, this is a really small image so you may not be seeing it - width 1x1 - Width is expressed in pixels per next/image documentation

> The width of the image, in pixels. Must be an integer without a unit.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#width

Comment: It looks like when used with `layout="responsive"` the width and height is used as the aspect ratio

Comment: agreed, I see the image retaining the width and height, however I do see the preview - made changes per your code - https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-breeze-nlbss?file=/pages/layout-responsive.js&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675 - click responsive or go here - https://nlbss.sse.codesandbox.io/layout-responsive. - Isn't this what you are seeing? Here is the preview I see - https://cln.sh/WTWkh9

Comment: If I click on the document (layout-responsive) in the network tab and then the preview tab, I can't see the image. The image itself on the website I can see

Comment: In the forked responsive example with 1x1 - I see the image - https://cln.sh/Fh2QkW in preview as you are describing. Can you post equivalent screenshot and what file type is being returned, in my case its `avif` - Even with JS disabled, I get a AVIF back

Comment: Yes the image itself is like yours, but on the document its not rendered in the preview. https://imgur.com/a/Lm5HvQd